# Australian light switch to smart switch

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

I am wanting to change my standard light switch over to a smart light switch here in Australia.

Work will get done by an electrician but I wanted to see if I'd need extra wiring etc (costs more) or if it's simpler than that.

Here's a photo of my current single gang switch along with a photo of the back of the new 3 gang switch (it'll be single but same setup just without A2 and A3)

Do I have the correct wiring available already?

New Switch:
 [image: new switch]

Old Switch:
[image: old switch]
[image: old switch 2]

Comment: Probably do-able as you appear to have access to hot, neutral and switched legs all at the switch location.  Not clear what the four terminals are on the new switch, do you have documentation?  Probably neutral, hot, and the two switch legs in that order.   It looks like you will need a separate terminal block or wire nuts (if they use those in Australia), as the old switch is being used for that but the new switch would not appear to accommodate all those wires.

Comment: Looks weirdly hobbyist. Are you sure it is legitimate product? Last I talked to an Aussie, they require some sort of documentation to prove it has the requisite safety testing. The market is veritably flooded with alarmingly unsafe Cheese junk.